# How to get listed on the "Who You'll Work With" section of a company page?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs, companies-page

The company I work for is running a few job postings on Stack Overflow Jobs. On our [company page](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies/citrusbyte) there's a section "Who You'll Work With" which displays a few profiles of developers. In the case of our company, the profiles it shows are using the random username and profile picture, and shows, and only shows, a few of our developers who are active on Stack Overflow.

I'd like to get myself added to the "Who You'll Work With" section. How do I do this?

Comment: Ask your HR department, or whomever else is managing your company account with Stack Overflow Jobs. They need to invite you to be added.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Whoever administers the company page *at your company* has to invite users to be listed. This is not something anyone else can do.

You'll have to ask around; if you have an HR department or dedicated recruiters, they are most likely also in charge of the Stack Overflow Jobs account for your company.