# What can I do to make my profile show up on the page of my company?

Tags: support, companies-page

Our company has a "Company Page", and I'd like my profile to show up in the "People" section because it's kind of cool. I have found [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351119/how-to-get-listed-on-the-who-youll-work-with-section-of-a-company-page/351120#351120), which tells us HR has to manually invite me. That's okay, but HR doesn't know how :). Could you tell us what to click?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, it's just that I was impatient. HR figured it out very quickly :)

For anyone wondering, it's: company page → company name → edit info → people → send invite link.